# general error mounting filesystems

Tags: 12.04, boot

Sorry for posting, but I have searched the website (and a bit the internet) since yesterday for a solution to my problem, but nothing worked for me so far. I just hope I am not duplicating.

Due to a system not working fine, I was obliged to turn on and switch off repeatedly my laptop where I have ubuntu 12.04 and windows 7 in dual boot. I ended up with an error message and ubuntu not starting. The message says :

```
General error mounting filesystems.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
:: no such a file or directory.
```

And two other lines stating the `dev/sda6` and `dev/sda7` (respectively my / and /home) are clean.

Furthermore, commands like `reboot` or `shutdown` will return message saying :

```
(command here) did not receive a reply. Possible causes include : the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired or the network connection was broken.
```

- I've done fsck for the 2 partitions with -a and -fv. No chance.
- I've checked fstab and it looked ok.
- I've tried to reinstall ubuntu 12.04 using the same partitions but
  the installation said it was successful, but didn't solve the issue.
- And I've also tried Boot Repair that said the grub was fixed (i think
  it was fine anyway) and here is the [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7049632) it gave me

I just don't know what to try anymore.